# minimum hardware requirements for increasing ram

Tags: memory, requirements

I have 5 years old PC with i3 processor (3.07GHz) 32bit operating system and 2GB ram.
My question is: is there any minimum hardware requirements for increasing ram memory, or i can just put another 4GB of ram in second slot?

Comment: Please include the *exact* make and model of your CPU, motherboard and RAM modules.

Comment: @DanielB Actually, I think this one can be answered well in the general.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It can be indeed. However, there are extensive considerations to make about Dual Channel, possible performance loss due to slower modules etc pp. For an inexperienced user, it’s easier to work with a specific answer.

Comment: @DanielB my scan is: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/scanview/A925BBF631D926C3 , i decide to go windows 8.1 64-bit and put another 4gb into another slot and test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are generally no minimum requirements for installing more RAM, assuming that the RAM fits (physically and electrically). So if you make sure you get memory sticks of the correct type (DDR2, DDR3, ...) and with correct timing (CL9, CL11, ...) you should be fine from that perspective.

However, you should be aware of two things:

- Many motherboards place an upper limit on how much memory you can use. If your PC is five years old, it is perfectly possible that you would run against that limit if you add 4 GB to your existing 2 GB. It's hard to say exactly what effects this would have.
- A 32-bit operating system will only allow you to use, at most, 4 GB without employing special tricks such as PAE. Since non-server operating systems generally do not do that, the operating system will in this case cap your usage to 4 GB minus some address space reserved for the system itself; in practice, the cap will likely be at 3 or 3.5 GB. Anything more than that will most likely not be of any use.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/889814/windows-8-wont-boot-after-upgrading-ram  this is a sequel :/

Answer (score 2):

Check the computer manufacturer's website for the maximum allowable memory and configurations.

You can also try [Crucial's memory scanner](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner).  It works rather well.

Comment: http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/scanview/A925BBF631D926C3  this is my scan. It means i can upgrade 2gb+4gb, or i can put only 1 4gb slot?

Comment: see the other answers. more than 4GB is useless to a 32-bit OS

Comment: My computer is capable of 64-bit OS and i will install 64-bit OS windows 8.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/889814/windows-8-wont-boot-after-upgrading-ram  this is a sequel :/

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only use 4GB of RAM on a 32-bit OS and even then only 3GB to 3.5GB will be available for use.
2. Buy another 2GB of the same RAM you already have or buy a 4GB stick that is compatible with your motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a specific question regarding your specific configuration. You can add the extra 4 BG of RAM, but the current configuration will not utilize it. You state an upgrade of OS in comments, so other points to consider as far as maximum amount and type:

Your mother board:
GIGABYTE GA-H55M-S2V LGA 1156 Intel H55 Micro ATX Intel Motherboard

> Memory Number of Memory Slots2×240pin
>
> Memory StandardDDR3 2200/1800/1600/1333/1066/800
>
> Maximum Memory Supported16GB
>
> Channel SupportedDual Channel

Knowing you are moving to a 64 bit OS, you have a few limitations if you subscribe to Windows:

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit versions - max RAM 16 GB

Windows 7 Business, Enterprise and Ultimate 64-bit version max RAM 192 GB

Windows 8 - 128GB

Windows 8 Professional - 512GB

Windows 8 Enterprise - 512GB

Comment: thx for answer :) i will go windows 8.1 and put another 4gb of ram and test it and write a feedback :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/889814/windows-8-wont-boot-after-upgrading-ram  here is the (sad) feedback..